# Shares Under IP

Tags: java, windows, networking, filesystems, samba

How to list all the available shared folders under a specific IP Address?

Mock code:

```
IP ip = new IP("10.0.0.9");

for(File share : ip.getSharedFolders){
    System.out.println(share.getName());
}
```

Is there a way in which this can be accomplished?

I want to make something similar to windows network explorer and I need to get all the shared folders under a specific IP so I can ggenerate a tree.

[image: Network explorer]

With the first level shared folders I can easely get the lower levels like this

```
for(File f : new File("//10.0.0.9/d").listFiles()){
                    System.out.println(f.getName());
```

Comment: " shared folders " - how shared ?

Comment: new File("//10.0.0.9/d/movies") Samba shares, network location

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the list of shares using the [The Java CIFS Client Library](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/) and in particular the [SmbFile.list](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html#list%28%29) method. Here is a small illustration of how to use this API:

```
SmbFile server = new SmbFile("smb://server/");
String[] shares = server.list();
```

Answer (score 2):

Java from out of the box does not support what you are trying to do.
You need to use libraries such as [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) to do this.

One easy/cludgy way out though would be to make sure that you have a drive mapping ( if windows or nfs/smb mount for other OSs) to the location and then treat it as a local file - using `java.io` APIs.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are accessible through the server IP address (network wise and permission wise) then sure you can list them all recursively by doing the following:

1. Get the remote folder name. Example `"//10.0.0.9/folder"`
2. Iterate through that folder just as you would do to list files in a local directory (see this link to know more about listing local files in a local directory