# What is a minimal valid UNC path?

Tags: windows, filesystems, unc

I want to make a library that (among other things) parses UNC paths, but I don't fully understand the grammar.

Common example is: `\\server\share\path`

Are all of those required for a valid file path? I can navigate to `\\server` (without `share`) using Windows Explorer, but I assume it is using some share discovery protocol, not something filesystem APIs understand — is this right?

Comment: You're right, Explorer under the hood invokes [NetShareEnum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525387%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to show shares on given server (and you see them as _folders_) but valid UNC is always \\server\share

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. A UNC path is required to have share name component.

Quoting MSDN:

> `UNC =  \\<hostname>\<sharename>[\<objectname>]*`
>
> The `<hostname>`, `<sharename>`, and `<objectname>` are referred to as "pathname components" or "path components". A valid UNC path consists of two or more path components.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465305.aspx