# How to read the list of files/folders on a shared location?

Tags: java, file, groovy

```
String sharedLocation = "\\\\hostname"
```

`new File(sharedLocation).list()` returns null. `exists()` returns `false` as well. I do not know if this is something related to permissions. I am running the script on Windows.

Instead when I open via **Windows -> Run** and type in \\hostname, the shared folders are listed as a part of auto-complete in the Run window drop down. Why can't I do the same with my java/groovy script? Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: Pardon the typo. The backslash was already escaped.

Comment: You need to escape backslashes. Try with "\\\\hostname" and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslashes in your string resolve to `\hostname`. If you want to get `\\hostname`, you must have two backslashes and escape them properly

```
String sharedLocation = "\\\\hostname"
```

[`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) is for existing files, but `\\hostname` is not a file or directory, but only a part of it. When you use `\\hostname\share`, you can `list()` all files in this share.

For listing shares, you can look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8480995/1741542, which suggests using the [The Java CIFS Client Library](http://jcifs.samba.org/).

With [`listRoots`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots%28%29) you can see already mounted shares.